# C file operation font in arabic

Tags: c, file-io

I've written a C program consisting of file operations (a .txt file).
When I open the output file in notepad, I don't read the contents in Latin script (or in simpler words - letters of the English alphabet), but some other script.
However when I open the file in C (using `fopen` etc.), I get the output in English (Latin script) again.

How do I view the output in English (Latin script) in notepad??

Comment: when you open a text file which is written in Arabic in Notepad, does it work correctly??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the classic "[Bush hid the facts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts)" problem.

In the Notepad file open dialog, you can see a drop-down that allows specifying an encoding. Since the file does not start with an unicode BOM, Notepad has to guess the encoding of the file (it does so as soon as you highlight the file in the list). And sometimes, it guesses wrong (but that's visible in the drop-down, and you can change it before clicking OK).